# How can I change my url while selecting the folder in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a  webpage containing test plans. In test plan there are teat cases and some folders.Now am specifying testplanId and folderId in url for  getting the list of testcases.How can I change the url by selecting the folderId.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testplan_view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewTestPlan(Model model, HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value = "testplanId", required = true) Long testplanId,
        @RequestParam(value = "folderId", required = false) Long folderId) {
    //changing the folder should redirect to folderId

    FlashMsgUtil.INSTANCE.checkFlashMsg(session, model); 
    EcTestplan testPlan = tpDao.findOne(testplanId);
    List<EcTestplanTestcaseMapping> tptcLst = tptcDao.findByTestplanId(testPlan);
    List<Object[]> tmLst = tpDao.findProductMetricsByTestplanId(testplanId);
    List<TestPlanMetricVo> testPlanMetricLst = BizUtil.INSTANCE.flattenTestPlanMetricsByProduct(tmLst);
    Integer totalPassCount = 0;
    Integer totalCount = 0;
    Integer totalNotRunCount = 0;
    for (TestPlanMetricVo tpm : testPlanMetricLst) {
        totalPassCount = totalPassCount + tpm.getPassCount();
        totalCount = totalCount + tpm.getTotal();
        totalNotRunCount = totalNotRunCount + tpm.getNotrunCount();
    }
    //Get all test cases associated with this test plan
    List<EcTestcase>testCaseLst = null;
    if (folderId == null) {
        testCaseLst=tcDao.findAllTestCasesByTestPlanId(testplanId);
    } else {
        testCaseLst = tcDao.findAllTestCasesByTestPlanIdAndTestFolderId(testplanId,folderId);
    }


    if (testCaseLst == null) {
        testCaseLst = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    List<EcUser> activeUsersLst = uDao.findByEnabledOrderByUsernameAsc(Boolean.TRUE);
    model.addAttribute("tptcLst", tptcLst);
    model.addAttribute("activeUsersLst", activeUsersLst);
    model.addAttribute("folderList", getFolderList(testPlan));
    model.addAttribute("testPlanMetricLst", testPlanMetricLst);
    model.addAttribute("testCaseLst", testCaseLst);

    model.addAttribute("testPlan", testPlan);
    model.addAttribute("tecaseCnt", totalCount);
    model.addAttribute("testPlanPassRate", Math.round((totalPassCount * 100.0) / totalCount));
    model.addAttribute("testPlanProgressRate", Math.round(((totalCount - totalNotRunCount) * 100.0) / totalCount));
    return "testplan_view";
}

private Map<String, String> getFolderList(EcTestplan testPlan) {
    // input: testplan
    // output: folder list, folder name should be full path
    // step 1: loop through all test cases of the test plan
    // step 2: use test case object, get test folder object
    // step 3: for folder, get all parent folders and use its name, construct string
    //
    String delimiter = "\\";
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<EcTestplanTestcaseMapping> testCaseMappings = testPlan.getEcTestplanTestcaseMappingList();
    for (EcTestplanTestcaseMapping testCaseMapping : testCaseMappings) {
        EcTestcase tc = testCaseMapping.getTestcaseId();
        EcTestfolder folder = tc.getFolderId();
        String fullpath = "";
        List<EcTestfolder> pFolders = folder.getAllParentFolderList();
        for (EcTestfolder pfolder : pFolders) {
            String pfoldername = pfolder.getName();
            fullpath += pfoldername + delimiter;
        }
        fullpath += folder.getName();
        map.put(String.valueOf(folder.getId()), fullpath);

    }
    return map;

}
```

Comment: Please give the proper explanation.

Comment: I have a webpage containing test plans. In test plan there are teat cases and some folders.Now am specifying testplanId and folderId in url for getting the list of testcases. How can I change the url by selecting the folderId.

Comment: What do you mean about changing the url? And even if you change the url, is your logic in this method still same with now?